# Media record API alternative for Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, video-capture, recordrtc

I need to record a video from a camera via browser,

I've done it for Chrome and Firefox using Media record API.

```
var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm; codecs=vp9'};
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);
```

Any alternative way to record a video from Safai browser?

Like a flash library but an open source one which can return the video as a blob object?

Thanks in advance

Comment: WebKit (Safari) team has already implemented MediaRecorder API in their latest preview release. However it isn't stable yet. (and still behind a flag) Hopefully we'll have a stable API in Safari-13 soon. In that case, you'll be able to record video-tracks as well. Here is relevant commit: https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/237106/webkit/ and the blog post: https://webkit.org/blog/8475/release-notes-for-safari-technology-preview-68/

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?
I know this is an old post but I am researching the same thing. almost 2 years later and safari still has MediaRecorder Api in preview mode. 
The most common alternative atm is using flash but as of Safari-14 they will be removing support for Flash. The other alternative is Web-RTC which streams the video to a server. And the recording/encoding is done server side with no way to access the blob client side before uploading.