# Is there an Alternative for the MediaRecorder API for Safari and IE?

Tags: javascript, audio-recording, mediarecorder-api

[Media record API alternative for Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040463/media-record-api-alternative-for-safari)

This question has been asked before on Stack Overflow, but it was not ever answered, properly nor did it list any alternatives.

Are there any alternatives to the MediaRecorder API for Safari and Internet Explorer. I'm looking to capture recorded audio without using any server. I want to be able to manipulate, store, and save data on the client-side.

Comment: https://github.com/ai/audio-recorder-polyfill

Answer (score 1):

As on Dec 17th 2020,Safari supports MediaRecorder API as an experimental Feature.
To enable it,you need to follow these steps

> Go to Settings → Safari → Advanced → Experimental Features
> → Enable MediaRecorder

[image]

Comment: i cant tell my customer to use this on PWA do you have any idea when they add it officially?

Comment: @javadbat they added it officially in iOS 14.5 released last April 25th https://caniuse.com/?search=mediarecorder